# Extracting a specific column from a .csv file, based on another column

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to extract the value of a column (let's call it x) only where another column (let's call it y) contains an entry equal to 1. If the entry is equal to 0 (or anything else) then I want it to be ignored. The entry to column x will then be written to a file in a specific format.

I have tried using `while read line` and in if statement to do this, but because I am already using `while read line` in extracting column y values I am having trouble getting it to work. How I extract column y and save it to the file is shown.

```
cut -d "," -f4 $input| sed '1d' | while read line;
do
printf -- "- name: `echo "$line" | tr a-z A-Z`\n  search_string: ['$line']\n  exact_match: False\n" >> output.txt
done
```

Example input:

```
host,port,process,monitor
localhost,1000,process1,1
localhost,1001,process2,1
localhost,1002,process3,0
```

Example output:

```
- name: PROCESS1
  search_string: ['process1']
  exact_match: False
- name: PROCESS2
  search_string: ['process2']
  exact_match: False
```

In case it is not clear column x is the process column and column y is the monitor column.

I would appreciate any help if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: paste a couple of lines from your csv as an input example, also let us know what do you want as output.

Comment: @Kent Thanks, I have uploaded sample input and output

Comment: where does `name: PROCESS1` come from? also the search string line, they are not in your input file.

Comment: @Kent the following line:```printf -- "- name: `echo "$line" | tr a-z A-Z`\n  search_string: ['$line']\n  exact_match: False\n" >> output.txt```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v input="$input" '$4==1 && $3==input{
     printf "name: %s\nsearch_string: [%s]\nexact_match: False\n", toupper($3), $3 }' input.csv
```

The above "awk-oneliner" gives the following output, if you have value "`process1`" in a shell variable `$input`. You can change the `$input` value to get different results.

```
name: PROCESS1
search_string: [process1]
exact_match: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `awk` is likely to be the better choice for this application, the `read` in `bash` can read multiple variables simultaneously based on the IFS (Internal Field Separator) variable.  Also, bash's parameter expansion can convert to upper case with the following syntax:

```
foo="process1"
bar=${foo^^}  # convert all characters to upper case
echo $bar     # prints "PROCESS1"
```

In your example, the following should work:

```
cut -d "," -f3,4 "$input" | sed '1d' | while IFS=, read procname flag; do
  if [[ "$flag" == "1" ]]; then
    printf -- "- name: ${procname^^}\n  search_string: ['$procname']\n  exact_match: False\n"
  fi
done
```

And it can be trimmed down even further:

```
sed '1d' "$input" | while IFS=, read -r host port procname flag; do
  [[ "$flag" == "1" ]] && printf -- "- name: ${procname^^}\n  search_string: ['$procname']\n  exact_match: False\n"
done
```